# Laravel 8 manejar 2 modelos con el mismo nombre

Tags: laravel

Tengo 2 modelos con el mismo nombre pero guardados en carpetas distintas, ósea en la carpeta Models tengo las carpeta octavo y noveno ambas con el modelo matemáticas con sus respectivas configuraciones y en su constructor determino la configuración de la conexión que van a usar, estos modelos manejan campos de tablas distintas y de distintas DB ósea tengo 2 DB una llamada octavo y otra noveno ambas tienen las tablas matemáticas lo que en la de octavo hay campos que en la de noveno no hay. Cuando intento crear las colecciones no puedo porque ambas clases son iguales aunque estén en un namespace distinto.

```
use App\Models\Octavo\Matematicas;
use App\Models\Noveno\Matematicas;

public function render()
{
   $octavo = Matematicas::all();
   $noveno = Matematicas::all();
}
```

Existe alguna manera de manejar estos modelos sin cambiarles el nombre o tendré que cambiarle el nombre al modelo obligatoriamente, cosa que no me gustaría.

Comment: Puedes apodar uno de ellos (o ambos) con **as**. Podría ser algo así: `use App\Models\Octavo\Matematicas as MatOctavo;` y luego `$octavo = MatOctavo::all();`

Answer (score 1):

Aunque es cierto que estan en distintos namespaces(carpetas), y esto te evita problemas en cuanto a Nombre unico a nivel de sistema, la verdad es que el detalle es que al momento de importarlo(use) a un archivo ya lo referencias por su nombre de clase, no por su nombre completo (incluyendo namespace) y a eso se debe tu problematica, las opciones que veo son las siguientes:

Usar el nombre completo y no trabajar con el use al inicio, no lo he probado para este caso especifico, pero debería funcionar.

```
public function render()
{
   $octavo = App\Models\Octavo\Matematicas::all();
   $noveno = App\Models\Noveno\Matematicas::all();
}
```

Usar Alias como comentaron arriba (puede ser tanto para uno como para los dos si deseas mantener homogéneos los nombres, es cuestion de gustos al final).

```
use App\Models\Octavo\Matematicas as OctaMatematicas;
use App\Models\Noveno\Matematicas as NoveMatematicas;

public function render()
{
   $octavo = OctaMatematicas::all();
   $noveno = NoveMatematicas::all();
}
```